# MPI - code only using one of two NUMA nodes

Tags: windows-10, mpi, mpich

This is a long shot but perhaps someone can help. 
I'm running a model (SWAN) on Windows 10. I'm using the MPI version using MPICH2 (1.4.1p1).

I have two NUMA nodes with 36 cores each. For some reason I can't run the model on all 72 cores.

I'm running the model using `mpiexec -n <np> swan.exe` or `swanrun inputfile <np>`. If I specify `mpiexec -n 72` the model starts 72 processes but only uses the 36 cores of one node. Even if I run 2 or more models at the same time they run on the same node leaving 36 cores pretty much idle.

I'm assuming I made a mistake when installing MPICH2 but can't quite figure out where I went wrong yet. I simply installed MPICH2 using the binary provided here (http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/1.4.1p1/) Is there some option I overlooked where I have to install it for both nodes separately?

Comment: Unless your system is configured to use two nodes, you typically need to pass this information on the command line via the `-machinefile...` option.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I should have mentioned that both nodes are CPUs one machine. So I have 2 CPUs with 36 cores each giving me 72 logical processors (I'm almost sure I'm using the nomenclature correctly?). Could I still use the machinefile option? How do I find the hostname of my CPU?

Comment: How many hosts ? How many sockets per host ? How many cores per socket ? How many threads per core ?

Comment: I still find it tricky to wrap my head around the distinction between CPU/processor/node/core/thread etc so I'm sorry if I'm not expressing myself correctly.

I have one machine so I guess 1 host? The computer has 2 sockets with 36 cores with 72 logical processors so I'm assuming 2 threads per core? Either way all the processes of my model run on NUMA node 0 instead of on node 0 and 1 if that makes sense?

Comment: no problem. i guess that unless you explicitly state `NUMA node`, most people including myself will assume node = host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I realised that I had multiple versions of MPI installed on my machine. While I'm still not sure as to why my model would only run on one of the NUMA nodes at a time (I'm not sure which MPI version `mpiexec` was calling) I uninstalled all MPI versions and did a clean reinstall. I can now run on all 72 cores.